# What is **the** way to interconnect two Smalltalk(s)?

Tags: smalltalk, gemstone, smalltalkx

If I would like to interconnect two Smalltalks, namely `Smalltalk/X` with `GemStone/S`, what approach would you recommend?  I would like to have an application in `Smalltalk/X` with persistent objects in `GemStone/S`.

Prior to any development I tried to investigate the issue.  I have found some open-source implementation done - I like to learn from others mistakes so I don't repeat them.

I have found an implementation for *Pharo* - [`gt4gemstone`](https://github.com/feenkcom/gt4gemstone) - Glamorous Toolkit for remote work with Gemstone/S.

I have found also from James Foster - [`Jade`](https://github.com/jgfoster/Jade) which achieves more as it is an

> Alternative Development Environment (IDE) for GemStone/S that runs on Microsoft Windows.

Where would you recommend to start? Would it be to read the `gt4gemstone` or `Jade`  and then come up with similar way to **interconnect** `Smalltalk/X` with `GemStone/S`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad to hear of your interest in GemStone (one of my passions!). The key to interoperability with GemStone is to provide a wrapper for the GemStone C Interface (GCI), a C library used to connect to GemStone. This is the method used by *every* GemStone client (whether C, Smalltalk, or something else) to communicate with the system.

For a Smalltalk example, see `GciLibrary*` and `GciSession` in [Jade](https://github.com/jgfoster/Jade/tree/master/sources).

For a couple other recent examples that might be cleaner starting points, see [`GciForJavaScript`](https://github.com/jgfoster/GciForJavaScript), [`GciForPython`](https://github.com/jgfoster/GciForPython).

For an older (ruby) example see [`gemstone_ruby`](https://github.com/jgfoster/gemstone_ruby).

So, I'd suggest that you investigate what `Smalltalk/X` has for a *Foreign Function Interface* (FFI), then follow the examples above to connect to GemStone.

Comment: Great answer!  I saw your 101 on GemStone (priceless), will have view it few times more because it is packed with information! Thank you for your hard work James.  I know ruby so I'll read that + your Jade client looks really nice - your code is nicely readable, I enjoy that (python is close to ruby so I could read that, with the javascript I try to avoid it as much as I can).  I did not manage to get to ESUG this year, I hope to be there next one.  Hope you enjoyed it!

Comment: I think the best approach would be to port relevant portions of Jade code. In Smalltalk/X you can load Dolphin's `.cls` files using: 
```
'/tmp/Jade/sources/GciThreadSafeLibrary.cls' asFilename readingFileDo:[ :s |
    ChangeSet fromDolphinPACStream: s
]
               
```
As for FFI, a quick glance to Smalltalk/X bytecode compiler and to `stc` compiles makes me think Dolphin FFI syntax is supported out-of-the-box. If not, automated refactoring from Dolphin to St/X syntax should be straightforward. `ChangeSet fromDolphinPACStream:` might also need some tweaks.

Comment: @J.V.  Thank you for the comment, will try to do so :).  By the way James what is the difference between Jade & Jadeite (Jade's fork, why was there a need for a fork?)

Comment: @tukan, In the case of Jade[ite], GemTalk wanted to develop an "official" IDE that supported Rowan and we agreed to a fork with a new name to let that project proceed with what was expected to be some significant changes. Yes, this could have been done with a branch, but it didn't seem as appropriate for the "official" version to be in my personal repository. I expect that Jade will incorporate Jadeite's features eventually, once things stabilize. Or maybe we will merge some of Jade's changes (e.g., support for Unicode) into Jadeite.

Comment: @JamesFoster I see, thank you clearning it up.  The unicode, you mean UTF-16 within Jade?  I have successfully compiled `DolpinVM` with `Jade` at VS 2019 Community Edition - there were some minor things to watch for, but otherwise than that it compiled just fine.